# Impact analysis in BO

Tags: business-objects

I'm a BI analyst and I inherited of an old Data warehouse not well documented. I'm trying to know if a table in my warehouse is part of universe/Report/Dashboard, so I get a view of the impact in Front-End of modifying this table. Of course I want to do that programmatically since I have dozens of fact tables.

I'm sure there is a way from BO !! I know that there is a SDK and Rest API but I admit I don't understand what should be used. I'm a SQL developer so I sure missed something.

From where should I start ? I need to know how to do things, what tools. Then I'll get an external developer to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have UNV or UNX type universes ? In any case would suggest first to document the universe using a third party tool. I have used http://biclever.com/software/unx-universe-documenter/ for UNX documentation

It extracts the objects used in the universe and their associated database fields / table etc in an excel file

Above would be a free approach, but will require some manual effort (checking each and every field for example)

Paid tools are there to do Impact Analysis with tools like 360 eyes, Sherlock, Metaminer, APOS and maybe SAP product like Information Steward

Hope this helps